# Getting unexpected results when type casting between long and double

Tags: java, double, type-conversion, long-integer

I have this code

```
public class LimitTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        long l;
        double d;
        l = 9223372036854775807L;// The largest number a long can hold.
        d = l;
        System.out.println(l);
        System.out.println(d);
        System.out.println(l == d);
    }
}
```

Now, the result it produces is kinda unexpected, but again, I am not very experienced with type conversions.

Output

```
9223372036854775807
9.223372036854776E18
true
```

Now, the two numbers printed are clearly **NOT EQUAL**, so why does `l == d` return `true`?

Answer (score 5):

The variables `l` and `d` have different types, so the expression `long == double` casts the `long` to a `double` ...

P.S. `l` is a bad variable name imho, since it looks a lot like `1` when glancing over code.

Answer (score 2):

`l == d` returns `true` because `l` is automatically promoted to `double`, and the result -- which is identical to `d` -- is then compared to `d`.

If you're interested, you can read up on the promotion rules in the JLS:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2

Answer (score 2):

> so why does l == d return true;

Because `long` is converted to `double` before the comparison. And hence the result is true.

This is specified in [JLS - Section 5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2):

> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.

You are seeing different result for `double`, because not all `long` values can be represented by a unique `double` value. So, you may possibly have many double values for a single long value. There is possible loss of precision while converting from `long` to `double`.

From [JLS Section 5.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1):

> A widening conversion of an int or a long value to float, or **of a long value to double**, may result in loss of precision - that is, the result may lose some of the least significant bits of the value.

Answer (score 2):

In order to compare two values they must have the same type. Here the long value is implicitly converted into the double type, and the result of the conversion gives the same value as an assignment.

The values are different in the first place because the double type has less "significance" (it has a 53 bit mantissa for storing actual digits; the rest of the bits are used for the sign and the exponent) than long (all 64 bits). Not all long values can be represented as a unique double value.

Answer (score 2):

`9223372036854775807` and `9.223372036854776E18` **ARE EQUAL**

Note the first 15 digits of precision `922337203685477` are the same. The rest of the first number `5807` gets rounded to a 6 so that the `E18` can be appended.

`9223372036854775807` in scientific notation is:

```
9.223372036854775807 x 10^18 == 9.223372036854775807E18
```

Compare:

```
9.223372036854775807E18  
9.223372036854776E18
```

**The value is stored with more precision than it is displayed with**, see this for proof:

```
    long l;
    double d;
    l = Long.MAX_VALUE;// The largest number a long can hold.
    d = l; //This is implicitly cast to (double)
    System.out.println("long: " + l);
    System.out.println("double: " + d);
    System.out.println("double back to long: " + (long) d);
```

> long: 9223372036854775807
>   double: 9.223372036854776E18
>   double back to long: 9223372036854775807

There is also the secondary issue of how floats and doubles are stored. While integer types (byte, short, int, long) are exact, float and double use IEEE754 mantissa-exponent style which allows them to represent a greater range of numbers but with less precision. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985